# SystemVerilog: How to create an interface which is an array of a simpler interfaces with different inputs?

Tags: system-verilog

What is the best way to create the below logic?

```
interface top_if(input rst_n[NUM_OF_modules],
                input clk[NUM_OF_modules]);

simple_if i_simple_if[NUM_OF_modules](.reset_n(rst_n[?]), .clock(clk[?]));
```

I need to send the `rst_n[x]` and `clk[x]` to corresponding `i_simple_if[x]`? what is the best way to do that. The `reset_n` and `clock` are 1 bit input signals of simple_if.

endinterface

Answer (score 1):

How about a `generate` loop:

```
interface top_if #(parameter NUM_OF_modules = 1) 
                  (input rst_n[NUM_OF_modules],
                   input clk[NUM_OF_modules]);

  generate
    genvar i;
    for (i=0; i<NUM_OF_modules; i++)
      begin : NAME
        simple_if i_simple_if(.reset_n(rst_n[i]), .clock(clk[i]));
      end
  endgenerate

endinterface
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3ALC

Comment: Thanks for Answering it.
I tried this way of doing it,
But i am facing the issue when i pass the interface : i_top_if.NAME[i].i_simple_if to a module 
the VCS is throwing an error saying: unresolved or generated instance name 'i_top_if.NAME[0].i_simple_if' is used.

Answer (score 1):

I tried two different methods:
1) generate loop for the Interface : simple_if inside the top_if.The VCS is not happy about it and throwing Illegally connected interface port, when i pass the generated interface to a module.
2) So i had to try the below method.

```
interface top_if #(parameter NUM_OF_modules = 1) 
              (input rst_n[NUM_OF_modules],clk[NUM_OF_modules]);

   simple_if i_simple_if[NUM_OF_modules]();
endinterface
top_if i_top_if();
generate
for (genvar i=0; i<NUM_OF_modules; i++) begin
assign i_top_if.i_simple_if[i].rst_n = xxx;
assign i_top_if.i_simple_if[i].clk   = yyy;
end
endgenerate
```